# Form the String

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to form the string in for loop.I get the one by one value in "name" variable.Now I need all the value in namevalues variable? the listbox having Pieter,John,Joseph Items.

How can i do this?

```
  for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
      string name = Listboxs.Items[i].ToString();
      string namevalues = ??;
    }

Expected Output is : Pieter*John*Joseph
```

Comment: Is the use of a loop necessary (such as for homework) or just how you are thinking of the problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since `Listboxs.Items` returns `ListBox.ObjectCollection` which implements `IEnumerable` interface, you can just use `string.Join` without for loop like;

```
string.Join("*", Listboxs.Items.Cast<string>());
```

should return

```
Pieter*John*Joseph
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`string.Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx) with `Cast()`

```
var namevalues = string.Join("*", Listboxs.Items.Cast<string>().ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
StringBuilder namevalues = new StringBuilder("");

for(int i =0; i<2; i++)
{
    if(namevalues.Length >0 )
    {
        namevalues.Append("*" + Listboxs.Items[i].ToString());
    }
    else
    {
        namevalues.Append(Listboxs.Items[i].ToString());
    }

}
```

Comment: Using the `+` operator on strings in a `StringBuilder` kind of defeats the purpose of what a `StringBuilder` does. You should use multiple `.Append()`s.